# MomentJS TimeAgo function, when passed a non-empty string

Tags: momentjs

So I needed to have `moment("2000/03/23", "YYYY/MM/DD").fromNow()` to return "20 years old" instead of "20 years ago", so I decided to pass in a string. It turns out that passing any non-empty string (ie. `moment("2000/03/23", "YYYY/MM/DD").fromNow("blah")`) removes "ago" from the return string.. so then you can just append " old" to the end of the result.

```
let age = moment("2000/03/23", "YYYY/MM/DD").fromNow("blah") + " old";
```

I am assuming this is non-documented, non-reliable result? Why does it do this?

**EDITED**: replaced timeAgo with fromNow, which is the function I was actually using in my code, but mixed it up.

Comment: whats timeAgo? is it of momentjs?

Comment: hi, sorry timeAgo was my variable name and I got it mixed up when writing out this question. I meant fromNow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update the format of your fromNow , then you might want to update relativeTime of updateLocale.

```js
moment.updateLocale("en", {
 relativeTime: {
    future: "in %s",
    past: "%s old",
    s: "a few seconds",
    ss: "%d seconds",
    m: "a minute",
    mm: "%d minutes",
    h: "an hour",
    hh: "%dh",
    d: "a day",
    dd: "%d days",
    M: "a month",
    MM: "%d months",
    y: "a year",
    yy: "%d years"
  }
});
let age = moment("2000/03/23 8:15:00", "YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss").fromNow();
console.log(age);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```